# How to set conditions in jsf tags

Tags: jsf-1.2

can any one help on the below.

I need to open a new browser tab using command link tag in jsf, only when a condition is true.

How to set conditions in jsf tags?

Comment: Could you paste an example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `rendered` attribute, and completing them with a EL expression. Using the `rendered` attribute, the link will only be shown if the condition is `true`.

If you want to open a commandlink in a new browser tab depending on a condition, you can easily achieve it using the `rendered` attribute:

```
<h:commandLink action="my_navigation_rule"
               rendered="#{!MyBean.booleanValue}" />

<h:commandLink action="my_navigation_rule"
               rendered="#{MyBean.booleanValue}" target="_blank"/>
```

As the `rendered` conditions are exclusionary, it will only be printed one of the commandLinks.

More info on JSF Expression Language (EL) (Very useful to *set conditions in jsf tags*) --> [here](http://dsc.sun.com/docs/jscreator/help/2update1/jsp-jsfel/jsf_expression_language_intro.html)

**Note**: I know the solution can be improved since you can use an EL expression to determine the `target` value, but in my opinion this solution is easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use managed bean  actionListener  of the commandMenu and then get the condition tested and redirect to the page in new tab if its true...

[image]

import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

public class PageBean {

```
String page;

public PageBean() {
}

public void getMenu(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    // Add event code here...
```

/* add your code to get and test condition and based upon the condition true and false conditon  get commandMenu Id of the menu clicked by the following way

be sure to give the id of the command menu the same name you want to open in the next tab upon menu click like in my case i have given the command menu id as page1
        String id = actionEvent.getComponent().getId();
        System.out.println(" Menu ID : "+id);
now set the fetched menu id to the page variable with the proper page extension and acccess the pariable in the action from the manged bean to redirect to the page in the next tab upon menu click after testing the validation */

```
    page = id;
    System.out.println("Value assigned to the page from the menu Id is :"+page);
}

public String getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(String page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public void dashContentEntryCheck(){
    System.out.println("entered inside dashboard content task flow");
}
```

}